# overwriting the existing file using file write action

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am facing a little problem

I am writing `.html` file from dynamic pages like

```
<cffile action="write" file="#filename#" output="#trim(content)#"   />
```

but problem is that if file already exists, the file will not be overwritten but the last modified date and time are updated some how.

I have also tried to delete the file first if file already exists, but .html show still the old contents. But if I manually delete the file then the newly generated file has actual contents.

Comment: Are you sure it's not being overridden? Try changing the output to something like output="#trim(content)#<!-- #Now()# -->" so the resultant file contains a timestamp.  How are you checking the file? If it's in a browser window, could caching be involved?

Comment: It's not in the documentation for some reason, but try adding, `nameconflict="overwrite"` to your cffile tag.

Comment: Make sure you are not writing twice (old and new content), because that's what it sounds like.